# Google map in jQuery UI tabs / Drupal behaviors.js

Tags: javascript

As you can see [here](http://123.click-monkey.net/node/2) the google map in the first jQuery ui tab loads correctly but the same map in second / third etc tabs does not load properly or loads off centre.

As mentioned [here](https://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.5/docs/tabs.html) the problem is that "Any component that requires some dimensional computation for its initialization won't work in a hidden tab, because the tab panel itself is hidden via display: none so that any elements inside won't report their actual width and height (0 in most browsers)."

I have read for example [here](http://www.liketly.com/forum/thread/10363/problems-with-google-maps-api-v3-jquery-ui-tabs/) that the problem is that the map loads after the jQuery UI tabs and so I need a jQuery snippet in my (Drupal 7) theme's behaviors.js to to make the map load before the jQuery UI tabs.

(Please note that the alternative solution of applying CSS to .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide  will not work for me because it causes problems elsewhere.)

Can anyone please tell me the code I need for my-theme.behaviors.js ?

my template.php =

```
<?php
function whitecross_160614_preprocess_html(&$variables){
// some comment here
    drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.tabs');
    drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery("#tabs-x, #tabs-y").tabs({event: "click"});
                jQuery("#tabs-x, #tabs-y").tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
                jQuery("#tabs-x li, #tabs-y li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");
            });',
        'inline');
}
```

HTML =

```
<div id="jqueryui-tabs-wrapper">
<div id="tabs-x">
<div id="tab-list">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Map 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Map 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Map 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>  <!--end tab list-->

<div id="tab-content">
<div id="tabs-1">
<iframe src="<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2483.645966939501!2d-0.14189000000000002!3d51.501364!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xa26abf514d902a7!2sBuckingham+Palace!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1403805298071"">https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2483.645966939501!2...</a> width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>  <!--end tab 1-->

<div id="tabs-2">
<iframe src="<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2483.645966939501!2d-0.14189000000000002!3d51.501364!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xa26abf514d902a7!2sBuckingham+Palace!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1403805298071"">https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2483.645966939501!2...</a> width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div> <!--end tab 2-->

<div id="tabs-3">
<iframe src="<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2483.645966939501!2d-0.14189000000000002!3d51.501364!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xa26abf514d902a7!2sBuckingham+Palace!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1403805298071"">https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2483.645966939501!2...</a> width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div> <!--end tab 3-->

</div> <!--end tab-content -->
</div> <!--end div tabs-x-->
</div> <!--end jqueryui-tabs-wrapper-->
```

Comment: what about simply making the opacity of the 2nd and 3rd 0 until initialization is complete. they would still display, just not be visible.

Comment: @ Geoff - thanks for your reply - do you mean .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {display:block; opacity:0;} - if so one problem is that the tabs will stack vertically so causing a big empty space below ie where the tabs are there but invisible.

Comment: opacity shouldn't affect position. and I would first try on the iframe itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to the comments, here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4krX2/) of what I was talking about. This is a quick example, but should be easily adapted to your own code. I altered the dimensions on the maps to show the change

CSS:

```
#toolbar
{
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    background:#000;
}

#toolbar li
{
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:100px;
    background:#fff;
    color:#000;
    border:1px solid #ffff00;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#maps
{
    position:relative;
    width:800px;
    height:600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#maps #tabs-1,
#maps #tabs-2,
#maps #tabs-3
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:800px;
    height:600px;
}

#maps #tabs-2,
#maps #tabs-3
{
    opacity:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="toolbar">
        <li id="toolbar_tabs1">Map 1</li>
        <li id="toolbar_tabs2">Map 2</li>
        <li id="toolbar_tabs3">Map 3</li>
    </div>

    <div id="maps">
        <div id="tabs-1">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2483.645966939501!2d-0.14189000000000002!3d51.501364!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xa26abf514d902a7!2sBuckingham+Palace!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1403805298071" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>  <!--end tab 1-->

<div id="tabs-2">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2483.645966939501!2d-0.14189000000000002!3d51.501364!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xa26abf514d902a7!2sBuckingham+Palace!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1403805298071" width="700" height="500" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div> <!--end tab 2-->

<div id="tabs-3">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2483.645966939501!2d-0.14189000000000002!3d51.501364!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xa26abf514d902a7!2sBuckingham+Palace!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1403805298071" width="600" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div> <!--end tab 3-->

</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery('#toolbar_tabs1').click(function(){
    jQuery('#tabs-1').animate({'opacity':1}, 200);
    jQuery('#tabs-2').animate({'opacity':0}, 200);
    jQuery('#tabs-3').animate({'opacity':0}, 200);
});

jQuery('#toolbar_tabs2').click(function(){
    jQuery('#tabs-1').animate({'opacity':0}, 200);
    jQuery('#tabs-2').animate({'opacity':1}, 200);
    jQuery('#tabs-3').animate({'opacity':0}, 200);
});

jQuery('#toolbar_tabs3').click(function(){
    jQuery('#tabs-1').animate({'opacity':0}, 200);
    jQuery('#tabs-2').animate({'opacity':0}, 200);
    jQuery('#tabs-3').animate({'opacity':1}, 200);
});
```

Comment: @ Geoff I can see your jsfiddle works fine - thank you. I think the more standard structure of jQuery UI tabs (or the one that I am familiar with) looks like this http://i.imgur.com/OOBG1gi.png ie using an unordered list. Will your answer work using the unordered list format or is there some problem about using an unordered list ?

Comment: it should work as anything really. I chose that format because that's what first came to mind... no other reason - it should be adaptable to whatever you want to use.